# how to remove dates from a cell and covert time to minutes of the day?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an excel columns like the flowing form column `B2:B1000`

```
10/05/2016 22:08
15/05/2016 11:16
19/02/2016 09:52
```

How can I make another column `C` in a format of times in minutes of the day from `B`

```
22*60+08
11*60+16
09*60+52
```

Comment: Try: `=MOD(B1,1)*24*60` and format cell as numbers. or `=HOUR(B1)*60+MINUTE(B1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented above by try either of the one:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `B1`

```
=HOUR(A1)*60+MINUTE(A1)
```

Or,

• Formula used in cell `C1`

```
=MOD(A1,1)*24*60
```

---

Note: Format cells as numbers.

---

Or, You could use `MOD()` & custom format as `[m]`

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `D1`

```
=MOD(A1,1)
```

---

Next select the column hit `CTRL + 1` --> From **Number** Tab --> **Category** as **Custom** and type `[m]`

---

Comment: when I try the first one why mine become`10/02/1900 00:00
`

Comment: You need to format the cells as numbers or keep general, I have mentioned that.

Answer (score 2):

use:

```
=--TEXT(MOD(B1,1),"[mm]")
```

[image]